# Where is this shift/reduce conflict coming from in Bison?

Tags: parsing, bison, lalr, shift-reduce-conflict, jison

I am trying to get the hang of parsing by defining a very simple language in Jison (a javascript parser). It accepts the same / very similar syntax to bison.

Here is my grammar:

```
%token INT TRUE FALSE WHILE DO IF THEN ELSE LOCATION ASSIGN EOF DEREF

%left "+"
%left ">="

/* Define Start Production */
%start Program 

/* Define Grammar Productions */
%%

Program
    : Statement EOF
    ;

Statement
    : Expression
    | WHILE BoolExpression DO Statement
    | LOCATION ASSIGN IntExpression
    ;

Expression
    : IntExpression
    | BoolExpression
    ;

IntExpression
    : INT IntExpressionRest
    | IF BoolExpression THEN Statement ELSE Statement
    | DEREF LOCATION
    ;   

IntExpressionRest
    : /* epsilon */
    | "+" IntExpression
    ;

BoolExpression
    : TRUE
    | FALSE
    | IntExpression ">=" IntExpression
    ;

%%
```

I am getting one shift/reduce conflict. The output of Jison is here:

```
Conflict in grammar: multiple actions possible when lookahead token is >= in state 6
- reduce by rule: Expression -> IntExpression
- shift token (then go to state 17)

States with conflicts:
State 6
  Expression -> IntExpression . #lookaheads= EOF >= THEN DO ELSE
  BoolExpression -> IntExpression .>= IntExpression #lookaheads= EOF DO THEN ELSE >=
```

Answer (score 1):

Your shift reduce conflict is detected because the `>=` is in the follow set of the `Expression` non-terminal. This is basically caused by the fact that a `Statement` can be an `Expression` and `IntExpression` can end with a `statement`. Consider the following input `IF c THEN S1 ELSE S2 >= 42`, if you had parentheses to disambiguate then this could be interpreted both as `(IF c THEN S1 ELSE S2) >= 42` and `IF c THEN S1 ELSE (S2 >= 42)`. Since the shift is preferred over the reduce, the latter will be chosen.

Answer (score -1):

Your issue comes from

```
 IF BoolExpression THEN Statement ELSE Statement
```

If the Statement after THEN contains an IF, how do you know if the ELSE belongs to the first or second IF?  See here for more information: http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Shift_002fReduce.html

The only 100% non-ambiguous fix is to require some sort of delimiter around your if/else statements (most languages use the brackets "{" and "}").  Ex,

```
 IF BoolExpression THEN '{' Statement '}' ELSE '{' Statement '}'
```

Comment: Sorry, no if/then/else problem this time. His `ELSE` is not optional which is a very good way too to avoid this standard pitfall.